# Use of different Spring view resolvers

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

I am new to spring. I would like to know the use of different view resolvers in spring . I read this link http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html (section 13.5.1) and many other links which i found in google. but I didnt get a complete idea of it. I would like to know when to use which view resolver. What are the advantages and disadvantages of each. It would be better if you can point me to some which contains a detailed explanation and that can be understood by newbies.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't work with that online tutorial, Spring In Action is a good place to start. Well written, and a little more descriptive.

```
http://www.amazon.com/Spring-Action-Craig-Walls/dp/1932394354
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9781933988139
```

The spring blog is great too:

```
http://blog.springsource.org/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/
```

Comment: Thank you stevebrown.. I will try that.